# How to add space between jumbotron when in mobile device size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So im building this website which looks like this in pc web size:

[image]

and when i resize the window to make it into mobile-sized window (phone), the jumbotrons turn into like this:

[image]

My question is that is there a way where i can add a space between the jumbotrons when it is in mobile-size? i do not want the jumbotrons to stick together just like in the picture i attached above.

my code so fo far, html:

```
<div class="container col-12">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="bg-card-1">
            <h1>Cardholder #1</h1>
            <p>Unique. Outstanding.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="bg-card-2">
            <h1>Cardholder #2</h1>
            <p>Stunning. Modern.</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="bg-card-3">
            <h1>Product</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid" id="bg-card-4">
            <h1>Product</h1>
            <p>Description</p>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css file:

```
#bg-card-1 {
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/0y2F6Gpp/3.jpg") no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}   

#bg-card-2 { 
  background: url("https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg-card-3 { 
  background: url("https://hatrabbits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/random.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#bg-card-4 { 
  background: url("https://i.postimg.cc/0y2F6Gpp/3.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4 you can set margin and padding based on break points (xs sm md lg xl).

To set a different margin based on screen-size, you can give the element margin classes with different break points and different margin values. Like this:

```html
<div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid my-3 my-lg-0" id="bg-card-3">
    <h1>Product</h1>
    <p>Description</p>
</div>
```

In this example the jumbotron would have a *y axis* margin (top and bottom) of `3` on `xs sm md` sized screens, but no y axis margin on screens that are `lg` or `xl`.

Note that to specify the `xs` breakpoint in Bootstrap, you simply do not add any break point at all in the class.

You can read more about spacing and break points in bootstrap at the links below.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/